# Issue with com.ibm.mq.jar

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ as client to put/get messages .

when trying to create **`MQMessage reqMsg= new MQMessage()`** getting below exception 
**`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices`**

But **com.ibm.mq.jar** is available inside my war.The same code is working in my windows machine but not working in linux(smoke) server.This will happen often but when i replace the existing mq jar with new one it used to start working again. But this time no luck.

Below some key points may help to figure out the issue.

1)we manually uploaded jars into artifact with version 7.1.0.6 since the server is running with same version and hence client side also need to have same version of jar.

But when i did **java -jar com.ibm.mq.jar** it shows as below

```
Name:        WebSphere MQ classes for Java
Version:     8.0.0.5
Level:       p800-005-160516.2
Build Type:  Production
```

2) i have below jars with version 7.1.0.6 in my war to put/get messages from/to server.

```
com.ibm.mq.allclient
com.ibm.mq.axis2
com.ibm.mq.commonservices
com.ibm.mq.headers
com.ibm.mq
com.ibm.mq.jmqi
com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi
com.ibm.mq.pcf
com.ibm.mq.soap
com.ibm.mq.tools.ras
com.ibm.mq.traceControl
com.ibm.mqjms
```

3) i am using jdk 1.8.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar did not exist prior to IBM MQ v8, so it can not be from a v7.1 install.  I would check the MANIFEST.MF file in each jar to check what version they are from.  On linux you can use this command `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Specification-Version`, replace the jar name with each jar.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? you wrote that you put the jar in your war..are you accessing MQ from a web app deployed in an application server? if so which one? how do you acces MQ? if your app is deployed in an app server it is better to use the RAR and the related JEE API that come with it and not deploy the jar file inside your app..Or maybe you are using the proprietary classes to connect to MQ? .please be more explicit about what you are doing exactly..also what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @titou10 I have a java client program and I am trying to post message to remote MQ server. Yes I am accessing MQ server from a web-app(war) and I am using tomcat8 as application server.Like other dependencies I added MQ dependencies in pom.My problem is I am getting CNF Exception some times and if I replace the com.ibm.mq.jar inside the war and restart the server it used to work. But this time it is not working. It's been working fine from last 7 months and all of sudden it stopped working with exception.

Comment: Did you see my comment above, the allclient file did not exist in v7.1.0.6.  The error you are receiving is likely because of a mis-match between jar versions.  Validate that all jar files are from the **SAME** version of MQ as a first step in solving your problem.

Comment: @JoshMc after correcting my jar versions by referring META-INF, issue solved.

Comment: Good to hear. I wrote it up as an answer.  Please accept it if the information was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` did not exist prior to IBM MQ v8, so it can not be from a v7.1.0.6 install.

Check the MANIFEST.MF file in each jar to check what version of IBM MQ it is from.

On linux you can use this following command, replace the jar name with each jar.

```
unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version
```

The error you are receiving is likely because of a mis-match between jar versions. Validate that all jar files are from the SAME version of IBM MQ.